# SDE Topology dirty areas don't go away

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, topology, versioning

Just looking for an explanation on SDE Topology dirty areas that don't go away.   My workflow involves editing a version of SDE data, then once finished I use the Validate Topology in Current Extent tool.  There is now a white box around my extent which looks good.
Next when I save, reconcile and post the dirty area boxes all return.

Is the picture below the way my data should look, or am I missing some steps?
Thanks,

Frank

[image]

The topo rules look something like this.

[image]

Comment: What are your topology rules?

Comment: I can post those if they are important, The dark red blobs are topo errors. It's the squares I was wondering about. I would have expected an area that was validated in the past to become an unhatched box.  If I were to validate this area, all the boxes disapear until I save, then they all come back.

Answer (score 2):

In many situations, a dirty area in you parent version will be present in your child version after you reconcile.  Additionally, in some situations reconciling can generate new dirty areas that aren't present in either version.

ArcGIS help:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Dirty_areas_in_versioned_feature_classes/00620000000q000000/

I don't really have a good solution for you.  Every time I have had to deal with versioned topology I've tried to make sure that both the versions are free of dirty areas before I rec/post.  I still sometimes end up with dirty areas though.